# Django rest framework + axios: Invalid preflight http method on first request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios

We have a rather strange situation with a react based frontend using axios to talk to our Django rest framework based backend.

When logging in a preflight OPTIONS request is sent by axios (as expected) but the first time the backend receives it, it seems to be malformed and thus results in a 401. 
However if I the retry, or even replay the exact same request using the browsers dev tool, the backend accepts the OPTIONS request and everything works as expected. We can consistently reproduce this.

The Django development server log looks like this:

First request

```
[23/Jan/2019 15:43:42] "{}OPTIONS /backend/api/auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 401
```

Subsequent Retry

```
[23/Jan/2019 15:43:52] "OPTIONS /backend/api/auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[23/Jan/2019 15:43:52] "POST /backend/api/auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 76
```

So as you can see, curly braces are added in the request method, which means that the request is not considered to be an OPTIONS request, and therefore a 401 is returned.

The django view

```
class LoginView(KnoxLoginView):
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication]

# urls.py (extract)
path('auth/login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='knox_login'),
```

The Axios request

```
axios.post('/backend/api/auth/login/', {}, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(creds.username + ":" + creds.password)
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            dispatch({type: 'SIGNIN_SUCCESS', response})
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: 'SIGNIN_ERROR', err})
        })
```

Some package version info

```
Django==2.1.4
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.11
django-extensions==2.1.4
django-rest-knox==3.6.0
django-rest-passwordreset==0.9.7
djangorestframework==3.9.0


axios@0.18.0
```

Comment: So, with some digging I've found that it's strictly the browser that's responsible for sending the pre-flight OPTIONS requests. However I have also seen {}POST and {}GET requests with the curly braces prepended.

the {} are present in the http method of the request from the very beginning, when Django (the wsgi server) reads the request out of the socket.

Very strange

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately I never got to the bottom of it, just sort of worked my way around it in my dev environment